# How Can I Create this Button on HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css

[That's what I need but i can't make that button and have it placed right there on margin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVi4u.png)
please help!!!

the google button is the one that i need to create

Comment: Start here -> https://www.w3schools.com/

Comment: Check out this example: https://codepen.io/mupkoo/pen/YgddgB?editors=1100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the "codepen" posted by Edgar Reynaga, I was able to quickly produce something close to what you are looking for.

```
<html>
    <button type="button" class="login-with-google-btn" >
        Sign in with Google
    </button>
</html>

<style>
.login-with-google-btn {
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 12px 16px 12px 42px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .04), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  color: #757575;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,Oxygen,Ubuntu,Cantarell,"Fira Sans","Droid Sans","Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;
  
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMTgiIGhlaWdodD0iMTgiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyI+PGcgZmlsbD0ibm9uZSIgZmlsbC1ydWxlPSJldmVub2RkIj48cGF0aCBkPSJNMTcuNiA5LjJsLS4xLTEuOEg5djMuNGg0LjhDMTMuNiAxMiAxMyAxMyAxMiAxMy42djIuMmgzYTguOCA4LjggMCAwIDAgMi42LTYuNnoiIGZpbGw9IiM0Mjg1RjQiIGZpbGwtcnVsZT0ibm9uemVybyIvPjxwYXRoIGQ9Ik05IDE4YzIuNCAwIDQuNS0uOCA2LTIuMmwtMy0yLjJhNS40IDUuNCAwIDAgMS04LTIuOUgxVjEzYTkgOSAwIDAgMCA4IDV6IiBmaWxsPSIjMzRBODUzIiBmaWxsLXJ1bGU9Im5vbnplcm8iLz48cGF0aCBkPSJNNCAxMC43YTUuNCA1LjQgMCAwIDEgMC0zLjRWNUgxYTkgOSAwIDAgMCAwIDhsMy0yLjN6IiBmaWxsPSIjRkJCQzA1IiBmaWxsLXJ1bGU9Im5vbnplcm8iLz48cGF0aCBkPSJNOSAzLjZjMS4zIDAgMi41LjQgMy40IDEuM0wxNSAyLjNBOSA5IDAgMCAwIDEgNWwzIDIuNGE1LjQgNS40IDAgMCAxIDUtMy43eiIgZmlsbD0iI0VBNDMzNSIgZmlsbC1ydWxlPSJub256ZXJvIi8+PHBhdGggZD0iTTAgMGgxOHYxOEgweiIvPjwvZz48L3N2Zz4=);
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 12px 11px;
}
</style>
```

Referenced codepen for assistance:  [Sign in with Google Button: Mirko Akov](https://codepen.io/mupkoo/pen/YgddgB?editors=1100)